# Smartdiagram Package: Changing Font Family

Tags: fonts, smartdiagram

I want to use sans serif fonts in a diagram, so I thought that including `\sffamily` would be enough, but something strange happens.

I include a MWE, where the first diagram is drawn using a serif font, and the second is drawn using a sans serif font. The only difference between them is the line that sets the font size. Is this behaviour ok?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{center}
\smartdiagramset{uniform sequence color=true,
sequence item uniform color=gray!50,
sequence item border color=black,
sequence item text color=black,
sequence item border size=1.2\pgflinewidth
}
\sffamily
\smartdiagram[sequence diagram]{PGF,Ti\textit{k}Z,Smartdiagram}
\end{center}
\caption{A sequence diagram.} 
\label{figure.seq2}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{center}
\smartdiagramset{uniform sequence color=true,
sequence item uniform color=gray!50,
sequence item border color=black,
sequence item text color=black,
sequence item border size=1.2\pgflinewidth,
sequence item font size=\normalsize
}
\sffamily
\smartdiagram[sequence diagram]{PGF,Ti\textit{k}Z,Smartdiagram}
\end{center}
\caption{A sequence diagram using sans serif.} 
\label{figure.seq}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
        \smartdiagramset{uniform sequence color=true,
            sequence item uniform color=gray!50,
            sequence item border color=black,
            sequence item border size=1pt,
            sequence item font size=\small\sffamily,  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        }
```

[image]
for *both*  diagrams and *not* the `\sffamily` before `\smartdiagram`